# Prestashop + Google Cloud SQL

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, php7

I am currently trying to setup a Prestashop 1.7 instance using Google Cloud Compute Engine and Google Cloud SQL (MySQL 5.7).

I managed to get to the installation page of Prestashop, but when I try to connect it to Cloud SQL, I get the following error:

```
    Your database login does not have the privileges to create table on 
    the database "prestashop". Ask your hosting provider:
    Storage engine MyISAM is disabled (Table creation is disallowed).
```

I spent a lot of time on this and I can't get it to work.
I understand that Prestashop uses InnoDB as a default SQL engine, and so does Cloud SQL.

That's why I don't really understand the source of this error.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4):

had the same problem here, took me one day of debugging...
Looks that prestashop guys did not check everything while transitioning to InnoDB.

To make in short:
`vi ./classes/db/DbPDO.php`

and in

```
public static function checkCreatePrivilege($server, $user, $pwd, $db, $prefix, $engine = null)
```

Look for:

```
if ($engine === null) {
        $engine = 'MyISAM';
    }
```

and patch like this:

```
if ($engine === null) {
        $engine = 'InnoDB';
    }
```

Hope it will work also for you.

Best whishes

Comment: Thanks for this, Alberto! I'm spinning it up in Kubernetes and ran into this issue. It would be great if the folks at PrestaShop could update their Docker container

Comment: 2022 and this issue is still present, you saved my day @alberto-viale